# ¿Numero máximo que soporte el IDENTITY en SQL SERVER 2008R2?

Tags: sql-server, identity

Tengo una consulta.
¿Cuanto soporta el IDENTITY en SQL SERVER 2008R2?--> Hasta que numero llega.!!
Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Identity` depende del tipo de datos de la columna, y estará dentro de las capacidades de ese tipo de dato.

Puede ser, por tanto:

```
TIPO DATO   MIN                                 MAX VALUE
TinyInt    0                                    255
SmallInt   -2^15 (-32,768)                      2^15-1 (32,767)
Int        -2^31 (-2,147,483,648)               2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)
BigInt     -2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808)   2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)
Decimal    -10^38-1                             10^38
```

Puedes verlo en acción, con algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE prueba1  
(  
 id_num TinyInt IDENTITY(1,1),  
);  

CREATE TABLE prueba2  
(  
 id_num SmallInt IDENTITY(1,1),  
);  

CREATE TABLE prueba3  
(  
 id_num int IDENTITY(1,1),  
);  

CREATE TABLE prueba4  
(  
 id_num BigInt IDENTITY(1,1),  
);  

CREATE TABLE prueba4  
(  
 id_num Decimal(10,0) IDENTITY(1,1),  
);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: también se puede usar el tipo de dato `DECIMAL`

Comment: Cierto @Shadow, he incluido el tipo decimal en la respuesta. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Un campo de tipo `IDENTITY` en SQL Server; puede tener cualquiera de los siguientes tipos

1. INT
2. BIGINT
3. TINYINT
4. DECIMAL

Nota: Si usas decimal, tu sentencia debería ser de este tipo `DECIMAL(3, 0)`
PARA QUE sea válido

La consola de SQL Server de hecho te puede devolver un mensaje como este donde te indica que tipos de datos son válidos

> Identity column 'id' must be of data type int, bigint, smallint,
>   tinyint, or decimal or numeric with a scale of 0, unencrypted, and
>   constrained to be nonnullable.

Dado lo anterior, entonces

**INT** Tiene una longitud de: `-231 (-2,147,483,648) to 231-1 (2,147,483,647)`
y de ahi puedes elegir el que quieras

**BIGINT** Tiene una capacidad de: `-2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)`